# Do the usb mini-monitors need a graphics card to act as a true 3rd window?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I've been looking at the little 7 inch monitors on amazon and Newegg, I haven't been able to be sure that they all don't need a graphics card or special configuration to have the monitor be a true 3rd monitor that is not a clone of one of the other two. The newegg 7 says it doesn't require a graphics card, but does not say anything about whether it would just try to display one of the existing screens if you have one.

So are all the usb monitors capable of being a 3rd window on all configurations or only special OS's, graphics cards, graphics drivers capable of making it so?

Comment: @Moab - Links to what?

Comment: "I've been looking at the little 7 inch monitors on amazon and Newegg"...Links to the products you are referring to. Curiosity on my part, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not need a graphics card. It will act as an additional monitor that you can drag stuff onto. Once installed, you should be able to configure it to either act as a second/third monitor or to mirror another monitor, just like any normal monitor.